# How to print Zend Form multiple times on 1 page with value from database

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I want to print the same form based on the database using zend form.

Suppose there are 3 people on db, the same form shall be printed 3 times with preload value from db. How can I do that?

I have following code:

In my Class Form function getform:

```
$form = new Zend_Form();
    $form->setAction("javascript:void(0)");

    include "Form/myElements.php";
    $personElements = new Elements();

    // Create fullname Field
    $form->addElement($personElements->getMustHaveValueTextField("name", "name* :"));
    // Create school Field
    $form->addElement($personElements->getMustHaveValueTextField("school", "school* :"));
    // Create save and remove button
    $submit = $personElements->getSubmitNoDecorators("save");
    $remove = $personElements->getSubmitNoDecorators("remove");
    $form->addElements(array($submit, $remove));

    return $form;
```

controller:

```
    $people = $db->people();
    $this->view->people = $people;

    include "Form/form.php";
    $form = new form();
    $this->view->form = $form->getform();
```

on my view as follow:

```
$i=1;
foreach($this->people as $person)
{
    // data to populate
    $data = array(
        "name" => $person['name'],
        "school" => $person['school']
        );
    $this->form->setName("formPerson".$i);
    $this->form->populate($data);
    echo $this->form;
    $i++;
    }
```

It is only populating the value for the last form.

So how do I actually have to do it using zend form?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
$form->reset();
```

inside your loop, after each rendering